# How to use elements of a JSON object to change attributtes in animation of a D3 bubble chart

Tags: animation, d3.js

I am new to D3. I make a chart with five bubbles, in wich "r" attributes are defined through a JSON member called "estudiantes". In the same chart there is a button. I am trying to make that when someone click in the button the "r" attribute change and be defined by other JSON member called estudiantes2010, but it don't work. If I use a fixed value for "r", the animation work and the radius of the bubbles change, so I guess that I am doing something wrong binding the JSON object to the r attribute, but I don't know what. Thanks!

Following is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3 Test</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="data/carreras.json"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <script type="text/javascript">

          var w = 2000;
          var h = 500;

          var SVG = d3.select("body")
           .append("svg")
           .attr("width", w)
           .attr("height", h);    

          var circulos = SVG.selectAll("circle")
           .data(jsonCarreras2002)
           .enter().append("circle")
           .style("stroke", "gray")
           .style("fill", "white")
           .attr("r", function(d) {return Math.sqrt(d.estudiantes/20);})
           .attr("cx", function(d, i){return 30+(i*140+170)})
           .attr("cy", 250);

          var button = d3.select("body")
            .append("input")
            .attr("type","button")
            .attr("value", "A button");

          button.on("click", function() {
            circulos.transition()
           .attr("r", function(d) {return Math.sqrt(d.estudiantes2010/20);})
           });



    </script>
    </body> 
    </html>
```

the json file is :

```
          var jsonCarreras2002 = [
            { "nombre": "Artes y Humanidades",
              "estudiantes": 29410,
              "estudiantes2010": 38767,
              "prueba": 20},
            { "nombre": "CC. Sociales y jurídicas",
              "estudiantes": 147482,
              "estudiantes2010": 140613,
              "prueba": 20},
              { "nombre": "Ciencias",
              "estudiantes": 18510,
              "estudiantes2010": 20189,
              "prueba": 20},
              { "nombre": "CC. De la Salud",
              "estudiantes": 22238,
              "estudiantes2010": 44636,
              "prueba": 20},
              { "nombre": "Ingeniería y Arquitectura",
              "estudiantes": 75947,
              "estudiantes20103": 59772,
              "prueba": 20}];
```

Comment: Works for me -- https://vida.io/documents/aPqG8nn66HJNCPXwq

Answer (score 1):

First, I think you have a typo in `json`, the line before the last, `estudiantes20103` should be I guess `estudiantes2010`

Take a look at this [example that I made based on yours](http://jsfiddle.net/VividD/kYRMM/). At the bottom I added one more button, that sets constant value for all circles, just for fun.

[image]

Play a little bit with buttons, you will see that both work. You can create more buttons if you wish to test more thoroughly.

Then just see what was wrong with your example, but in any case you have a working solution.

One difference is that I encapsulated data definition in function `getData()`, try that too.

If you have time, you can perhaps take a look at additional useful and even more complicated, but also beautiful example [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20814073/circle-packing-diagram-transition-between-two-set-of-values).

[image]