# D3 v5 version of 'Circle-packing diagram - transition between two set of values' example

Tags: d3.js, visualization, hierarchy

** Note: I have now added a link to a working 'Fiddle' code example of how far I have got to illustrate my problem. This can be found towards the base of this post. **

Hi. I'm trying to replicate this example of a '[Circle-packing diagram with transitioning between two set of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20814073/circle-packing-diagram-transition-between-two-set-of-values)' and am struggling to convert the v3 code to v5 (I have to use v5, as opposed to any of the more recent versions of D3).

I have copied and modified how I believe the code needs changing but am currently getting the circles transitioning, but moving between different parent node circles; which is not what I expect or want.

Whereas the d3 v3 version linked to above generates the new data  to transition to on the fly after a user clicks a new state button, I am wanting to transition the chart to reflect a new attribute selected within each JSON element of the loaded JSON object; here I want to transition the chart between 'size1' and 'size2' after user requests the change. e.g.

```
                {
                    "name": "axis",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Axes",
                            "size1":1000,
                            "size2": 1302
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Axis",
                            "size1":1000,
                            "size2": 24593
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "AxisGridLine",
                            "size1":1000, "size2": 652
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "AxisLabel",
                            "size1":1000, "size2": 636
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "CartesianAxes",
                            "size1":1000, "size2": 6703
                        }
                    ]
```

Note that the size and structure of the JSON will not have changed; it is loaded when the chart is built, and is the base for both 'size1' and 'size2' chart attribute views. The number of node circles will therefore remain the same, as will the hierarchy structure within which they exist for both views using 'size1' and 'size2' attributes to scale the node circles by. I am expecting just for each circle to transition to its new 'size2' size within the parent node it resides when viewed as 'size1'

The chart builds correctly on load, using 'size1' as the default selected attribute to scale the individual nodes by; but when the user chooses to rescale the circles using attribute 'size2', the individual nodes resize correctly (I tested this by setting value of every 'size2' instance to the same value of 1,000. They do however move about with the bounds of the main largest node 'root' circle, often changing the 'parent' circle within which they are found.

Each time I build the chart on loading the page, or transition to a new state, I use the d3 v5 .hierarchy() .and pack() library functions which are notionally different to the D3 v3 code I'm trying to copy.

'dataAttributeToUse' is the variable that holds which JSON attribute I want to scale the circles by.

I've created this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbayliss3/tsj3ckv1/) showing what I have currently [not] working. Click on the HTML button to switch between attributes contained within the 'flare' JSON, and you will see the circles incorrectly moving between different larger container parent circle nodes. This is obviously incorrect.

```
config.root = d3
.hierarchy(config.root)
.sum(function (d) {
return d[dataAttributeToUse];
})
.sort(function (a, b) {
return b.value - a.value;
});

var focus = config.root;
var nodes = pack(config.root).descendants();
var view;
```

Comment: After some more work I have now got a d3 v5 version of the circle packing visual working by transitioning between two attribute [states] given in the underlying JSON data. An updated jsfiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/tjbayliss3/rq4un7sg/2/. main points to note are that the 'name' attribute (or your equivalent in the underlying data needs to be unique. It is possible to generator you own unique identifier if the d.data.name 'key' is not unique in your data (e.g. 'name':'data' is defined twice in the original full version of flare.json on different paths/levels.